# Multiple Fragments dynamically in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity that is divided into sections. Each section is a fragment and I'm using  [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView):

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gray_skeleton"
                android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/fragmentGrafic"
                   android:name="Fragment1" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/fragmentGrafic"
                   android:name="Fragment2" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/fragmentGrafic"
                   android:name="Fragment3" />

...
</LinearLayout>
```

But now I have to hide/show fragments depending on some validations. I was using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` but its not too optimal because the Fragment is not destroyed.

- How can I remove or add more fragments dynamically?
- Do I have to create 'n' FragmentContainerView's in XML depending on my 'n' Fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I remove or add more fragments dynamically?

[API to remove fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#remove(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)). [API to add fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#add(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)).

> Do I have to create 'n' FragmentContainerView's in XML depending on my 'n' Fragments?

No, you do not. You would `add`, `remove`, or `replace` as needed. The specifics would depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Didnt realized that you can have multiple fragments in the same container, but how can u manage the layout params between all the fragments in the same container?

Comment: Within a single `FragmentContainerView`, all fragments are stacked on top of one another and take up the full size of the container (like a `FrameLayout`); you do not get the control the layout params of individual fragments in the same `FragmentContainerView`.

Comment: @GorkyMuñoz you would control the layout parameters within each Fragment's own root view. The container holding the fragments is just a shell.